# Do plants have souls

Tags: soul

According to science plants are made up of living cells and can grow and reproduce and many of their biological systems are similar to animals and humans.

So do plants have souls like animals and human beings? Please give logic in both sides of the answer.

Comment: Beyond the scope of humans and their intellect and if answered, could be ambiguous and contradictory.

Comment: @azam,The second quotation of "American Muslim" is from Bukhari which is hard to ignore and the first one is also very valid and therefore you need to come up with strong references from quran and hadiths on this matter to change my mind.

Comment: http://quran.com/33/72 when mountains can take decisions in front of God, it could be that even they have souls which only God can perceive not you and me. We think they're immovable objects. Leave that, if plants don't have souls, then how are they being born and how are they dying?

Comment: @azam, you need to look up into tafseer which supports your arguments as the interpretation of such verses are diverse and if a tafseer supports your argument then i will believe your arguments otherwise it is your opinion unlike the "American Muslim" who came up with clear cut words to support his argument but since your argument may have a little weight so for now i will untick that answer but if you fail to provide an answer then i will again approve it. Make sure you provide your answer in the answer column for me so i can compare and take the decision. Please give your argument soon.

Comment: I'm not here to answer your question unless you define soul properly in your question. I was just telling, we are not the right people to discuss the matters of Ghaib, and saying precisely whether they have souls or they don't have souls is beyond the scope of us humans, unless we have **explicit proof** from the books.

Comment: @azam,Maybe you are right and i will research more on it before approving the answer again. Meanwhile, you are welcome to add anything by giving reference but i have to admit your opinion also have weight.

Comment: [quran.com/64/1](http://quran.com/64/1) يُسَبِّحُ لِلَّهِ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَمَا فِي الْأَرْضِ ۖ لَهُ الْمُلْكُ وَلَهُ الْحَمْدُ ۖ وَهُوَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ
"Whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth is exalting Allah .To Him belongs dominion, and to Him belongs [all] praise, and He is over all things competent."
To my understanding something that does't have a soul can't worship...
Can all those addressing the question...take this into consideration when answering.

Answer (score 1):

Plants do not have souls. It is a general fact that anything that has soul and the soul leaves died. This can be said about Humans and Animals but not Plants.

Additionally, let's look at the following Hadith from the Prophet PBUH (Translating only relevant parts):

> قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أتاني جبريل فقال إني كنت أتيتك البارحة فلم يمنعني أن أكون دخلت عليك البيت الذي كنت فيه إلا أنه كان في باب البيت تمثال الرجال وكان في البيت قرام ستر فيه تماثيل وكان في البيت كلب فمر برأس التمثال الذي بالباب فليقطع فليصير كهيئة الشجرة ومر بالستر فليقطع ويجعل منه وسادتين منتبذتين يوطآن ومر بالكلب فيخرج ففعل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم وكان ذلك الكلب جروا للحسن أو الحسين تحت نضد له فأمر به فأخرج
>
> The prophet said Gibreal came to me and said I tried to come yesterday but was held to enter your house because in front of the door was a statue and a dog. The prophet then ordered the dog be removed and broke off the head of the statue so that it looks like a tree. [Abu Daood 4158, Tirmadi 2806]

As you can clearly see, the statue was forbidden when it looked like a Human, but once it looked like a tree it didn't reflect a soul to worship so it was fine. It was also reported that:

> وخرج مسلم عن سعيد بن أبي الحسن قال: جاء رجل إلى ابن عباس فقال: إني رجل أصور هذه الصور فأفتني فيها، فقال: (ادن مني) فدنا منه، ثم قال: (ادن مني) فدنا منه، حتى وضع يده على رأسه فقال: أنبئك بما سمعت من رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، سمعت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يقول: ((كل مصور في النار يجعل له بكل صورة صورها نفسا تعذبه في جهنم)) وقال: (إن كنت لا بد فاعلا فاصنع الشجر وما لانفس له) وخرج البخاري قوله: إن كنت لا بد فاعلا
>
> Ibn Abas told a person who drew things that if you are to draw, draw things like trees and whatever doesn't have a soul in it. [Bukhari 2225]

The second hadith is more of an opinion of Ibn Abbas, but there are many hadiths that prohibit the drawings of things with souls, but the prophet encouraged the drawings of trees which implicitly means trees do not have souls.

Comment: what do you mean Animals do not have souls?

Comment: @servant That was a typo, should've been plants not animals.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim, Brilliant answer, thank you for increasing my knowledge.

Comment: http://quran.com/33/72 If plants don't have souls, how can mere static mountains take **intelligent decisions**? To make it simple, if they don't have souls, how are they born and how are they dying? See also [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/the-mystery-of-plants#comment44986_25999)

Comment: If worshiping a soul is what you're trying to prove, then I've seen many people who worship soul less objects like pens, books, trees, stones of various sizes and what not. And second hadith is not from the Prophet (pbuh). With this, **you** could not convince me plants don't have souls.

Answer (score -1):

We need to agree on a definition of the soul, or at least an observable aspect of it. I would say that one such aspect is having feelings.

Judging by this aspect, the answer is yes. Seerah tells us they do. You may read about the story of the tree that felt sad when the messenger (PBUH) left it. The story and hadith are in Arabic here:
http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=71&idto=71&bk_no=118&ID=77

Relevant ahadith:

- [In Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/94):

  > Narrated Anas bin Malik:
  >   That he heard Jabir bin `Abdullah saying, "The roof of the Mosque was built over trunks of datepalms working as pillars. When the Prophet (ﷺ) delivered a sermon, he used to stand by one of those trunks till the pulpit was made for him, and he used it instead. Then we heard the trunk sending a sound like of a pregnant she-camel till the Prophet (ﷺ) came to it, and put his hand over it, then it became quiet."
  >   حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي أَخِي، عَنْ سُلَيْمَانَ بْنِ بِلاَلٍ، عَنْ يَحْيَى بْنِ سَعِيدٍ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي حَفْصُ بْنُ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، أَنَّهُ سَمِعَ جَابِرَ بْنَ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ يَقُولُ كَانَ الْمَسْجِدُ مَسْقُوفًا عَلَى جُذُوعٍ مِنْ نَخْلٍ فَكَانَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم إِذَا خَطَبَ يَقُومُ إِلَى جِذْعٍ مِنْهَا، فَلَمَّا صُنِعَ لَهُ الْمِنْبَرُ، وَكَانَ عَلَيْهِ فَسَمِعْنَا لِذَلِكَ الْجِذْعِ صَوْتًا كَصَوْتِ الْعِشَارِ، حَتَّى جَاءَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَوَضَعَ يَدَهُ عَلَيْهَا فَسَكَنَتْ‏.‏
- [In Jami` at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B0%D8%B9%20%D8%AD%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%86)

Answer (score -3):

i think plants have simpler souls than animals, and animals' souls are simpler than human soul. and single-cell organisms' and viruses' souls are simpler than souls of plants, and things like cars and stones have more simple souls than viruses.

logic/proof is : what is soul? soul is character, psyche, spirit, nature, temper.

Comment: References please????

Comment: http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=nfs